# How to declare a button event in a class?

Tags: events, header, c++-cli, declare

i'm new here and hope you can help me...
i've got a header "Messagebox.h" for my window layout (i'm using visual studio 2013) and i want to declare the click-event in a class "Class.cpp" instead of the header.

this is my Messagebox.h

```
#pragma once

class Banana;
class Apple;

namespace Fruitsalat {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Zusammenfassung für Messagebox
/// </summary>
public ref class Messagebox : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Messagebox(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Konstruktorcode hier hinzufügen.
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Verwendete Ressourcen bereinigen.
    /// </summary>
    ~Messagebox()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected:

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Designervariable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Erforderliche Methode für die Designerunterstützung.
    /// Der Inhalt der Methode darf nicht mit dem Code-Editor geändert werden.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(197, 226);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->button1->Text = L"quit";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Messagebox::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(102, 226);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 1;
        this->button2->Text = L"send";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Messagebox::button2_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
        this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
        this->textBox1->ReadOnly = true;
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->BackColor = Color::White;
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(260, 195);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // Messagebox
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 261);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Name = L"Messagebox";
        this->Text = L"Messagebox";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->Close();
}
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){
    //declare this in Apple.cpp or Banana.cpp
}
};
}
```

can i do that and how?

Comment: and why not? i AM programming in C++ O.o

Comment: ah, okay, i see! ^^
my fault

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking about how to type the appropriate lines in the header file vs. the source file, so that you can move the implementation of your method out of the header and into the source file. Is that correct?

There's nothing innately special about the event handler method. It is just a regular method on your class, so you can implement it in the same way: Declare the method in the .h file, implement the method in the .cpp file.

In `MyClass.h`:

```
public ref class MyClass : public SomeGUIClass
{
private:
    void button2_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e);
};
```

In `MyClass.cpp`:

```
void MyClass::button2_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    this->textBox->Text = "Woo!";
}
```

Comment: the problem is, it is not in the header of the class.
(sorry, i missed that info in my question - but i edited it)

Comment: I don't understand. Your class definition (that's the part that starts `public ref class MyClass`) is in the header file. You want to move not just the method implementation, but the *declaration* as well out of the header file? Sure, you can do that, but then it's not part of the class anymore, it's just a global method.

Comment: and how can i do that? how can my class Apple or Banana use/declare the click-method?